# Running unit tests from the tested module

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a bunch of modules and for each module I have a `unittest` based test. I want to define the main in each module to run its tests, but I get import errors because of import loops (specifically when I use `from mymodule import myclass` in the test.
I suspect this is a solved problem, so - what should I put in my module's main to run its corresponding test?

Comment: show the corresponding code in your main! i'm doing exactly the same with `unittest.loadTestsFromModule` and don't have any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you've got a file (lets call it mymodule.py) that looks like this:

```
import unittest
from mymoduletests import MyModuleTests

class myclass(object):
    def somefunction(self, x):
        return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and a separate file (lets call it mymoduletests.py) that looks something like this:

```
import unittest
from mymodule import myclass

class MyModuleTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_somefunction(self):
        m = myclass()
        self.assertEqual(4, m.somefunction(2))
```

If you run mymodule.py you get the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mymodule.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mymoduletests import MyModuleTests
  File "/Users/srgerg/Desktop/p/mymoduletests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mymodule import myclass
  File "/Users/srgerg/Desktop/p/mymodule.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mymoduletests import MyModuleTests
ImportError: cannot import name MyModuleTests
```

However, if you change mymodule.py to this:

```
class myclass(object):
    def somefunction(self, x):
        return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    from mymoduletests import MyModuleTests
    unittest.main()
```

and then run it, you get:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Have I understood you correctly?